# Extracting into named groups parts of a url via Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to get parts of a url with named groups with Regex for .Net

The examples are

```
/find/products/
/find/products/test/
/find/products/test/with/
/find/products/test/with/lids/
/find/products/test/page/3/
/find/products/test/with/lids/page/3/
```

The results from the regex should be

```
Query: Test
Subset: Lids
Page: 3
```

or null depending in the url, I want named groups so I can extract it later dynamically.

My attempt is

```
^/find/products/(?<Query>\w*)?
(?<SubsQuery>/with/(?<Subset>\w*)?/)?
(?<PageQuery>/page/(?<Page>\d)?/)?
$
```

From the example

```
/find/products/ (matches)
/find/products/test/ (doesnt)
/find/products/test/with/ (doesnt)
/find/products/test/with/lids/ (matches)
/find/products/test/page/3/  (matches)
/find/products/test/with/lids/page/3/ (doesnt)
```

Which means I'm missing some optional stuff ?:() , but I can't seem to see where, think I've had too much regex for one day :)

If anyone could help me it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this here

```
Match result = Regex.Match(str, @"^/find/products/(?<Query>\w*)?/?
    (?<SubsQuery>with/(?<Subset>\w*))?/?
    (?<PageQuery>page/(?<Page>\d)?/)?
    $",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

The problem is, that you miss the last slash in e.g. "/find/products/test/", because this was covered from the next (not available) group.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have too many slashes (`/`) in your regex. That is, you have one at the end of one part and then the beginning of the next part. The easiest way to fix it is to have slashes at the end of every part:

```
^/find/products/(?<Query>\w*/)?
(?<SubsQuery>with/(?<Subset>\w*/)?)?
(?<PageQuery>page/(?<Page>\d/)?)?
$
```

Of course this puts the slashes into your named groups. In order to remove them you need more groups:

```
^/find/products/((?<Query>\w*)/)?
(?<SubsQuery>with/((?<Subset>\w*)/)?)?
(?<PageQuery>page/((?<Page>\d)/)?)?
$
```

Comment: I think stema's answer was a bit better since it didn't have no-named groups, but your's was useful, so thank you!